# При смене картинок через js они грузятся каждый раз заново

Tags: javascript, html

Есть галерея, которая переключается с помощью опций. В зависимости от опции в галерею загружается коллекция соотвествующих картинок. Пример.

```
images_array.forEach(function(item){
    html+='<div class="item">';
    html+='<a href="'+item.popup+'" class="popup-image">';
    html+='<img src="'+item.image+'" alt="'+item.title+'">';
    html+='</a>';
    html+='</div>';
});
$gallery.html(html);
```

Вопрос в следующем. Почему если повторно загрузить картинки, которые грузились ранее, они начинают скачиваться заново, а не берутся из кеша браузера и как это решить? Еще пример с большими картинками.

```js
var images = ['https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/DigitalGlobe_WorldView2_50cm_8bit_Pansharpened_RGB_DRA_Rome_Italy_2009DEC10_8bits_sub_r_1.jpg',
'https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/DigitalGlobe_WorldView1_50cm_8bit_BW_DRA_Bangkok_Thailand_2009JAN06_8bits_sub_r_1.jpg'];
var current = 0;
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML = "<img src='" + images[current] + "' alt=''/>";
  current = (current + 1) % 2;
}
```

```css
.container,
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/DigitalGlobe_WorldView1_50cm_8bit_BW_DRA_Bangkok_Thailand_2009JAN06_8bits_sub_r_1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: В показанном вами примере картинки берутся из кэша

Comment: @andreymal у меня они начинают грузиться заново при переключении, надо только дождаться полной загрузки, если переключить во время загрузки - загрузка продолжается с того же места.

Comment: Я дождался полной загрузки и потом они всё равно берутся из кэша

Comment: как вы обои определяете и кэша они берутся или нет?

Comment: @Grundy визуально видно, плюс вкладка Сеть в Devtools.

Comment: "визуально" - совсем не показатель. Проверь, включена ли у тебя галочка `disable cache` в devtools, возможно в этом причина

Comment: @Grundy вот жеж. Как говориться, слона и не заметил. Все, разобрался. Спасибо большое.